# why sqlite donot give error for wrong input type of data?

Tags: sqlite

why sqlite do not give error for wrong input type of data? for example the database needs integer, but the input is '5' why no error occurred? why company still uses it? I have some knowledge about sql by creating database and interact with mysql or MSSQL, but never experienced sqlite

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not give errors for wrong input types because there are no wrong input types.

All types are allowed; this is called [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and is a feature.